# How to use SqlStdOperatorTable.IN with RelBuilder?

Tags: apache-calcite

I'm trying to build a rexNode similar to <SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x IN ("bar1", "bar2")> using RelBuilder. But I can't really find any example or any test using SqlStdOperatorTable.IN. Could please somebody share any? Or explain how to use SqlStdOperatorTable.IN.

Saw something [here](https://github.com/apache/calcite/pull/2201), but it didn't help much and didn't work for me(

```
    RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(calciteConfig);
    RelRunner relRunner = calciteConnection.unwrap(RelRunner.class);

    builder.scan("dremio", "test1");
    RexBuilder rexBuilder = new RexBuilder(new SqlTypeFactoryImpl(RelDataTypeSystem.DEFAULT));
    RexNode rexNode = rexBuilder.makeCall(
            SqlStdOperatorTable.IN,
            builder.field("device_type"),
            rexBuilder.makeLiteral("TABLET"),
            rexBuilder.makeLiteral("MOBILE"));
    RelNode test1 = builder
            .filter(rexNode)
            .limit(10, 100)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `RelBuilder#in` or `RexBuilder#makeIn` APIs. Here is the test case:

```java
  @Test void testIn() {
    final RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(config().build());
    builder.scan("EMP");

    final RexNode literal1 = builder.literal("foo");
    final RexNode literal2 = builder.literal("bar");

    RexNode inRex = builder.in(builder.field("ENAME"), ImmutableList.of(literal1, literal2));
    RelNode root = builder.filter(inRex)
            .build();

    final String expected = "" +
        "LogicalFilter(condition=[SEARCH($1, Sarg['bar', 'foo']:CHAR(3))])\n" +
        "  LogicalTableScan(table=[[scott, EMP]])\n";
  }
```

If you want to get more context why a check is present in the constructor of `RexCall()`
which is `assert operator.kind != SqlKind.IN` please refer to this [CALCITE-4173](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-4173)

Comment: Cool, missed this API... Thank you a lot! Now it works fine for me.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I will note that if you want to write `IN (SELECT ... )`, you need to use the other `RelBuilder.in` method that was added in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-3524. See the [test case](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/bf56743554ea27d250d41db2eb83806f9e626b55/core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/RelBuilderTest.java#L2442).